# Hadoop error running the file gives the error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, sequential

I have a Hadoop java file for running it in my eclipse IDE and When I run this hadoop to generate the sequence file from Input text file I getting the following error.

```
   Feb 12, 2013 6:33:02 PM org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key <init>
   WARNING: uri=file:///

   javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Login failed: Cannot run program "whoami":        CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at     
                    org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGroupInformation.java:250       )
       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGroupInformation.java:275)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UnixUserGroupInformation.login(UnixUserGroupInformation.java:257)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.login(UserGroupInformation.java:67)

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:1438)

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1376)

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:215)

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:120)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:319)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:313)

at main.LineIndexer.main(LineIndexer.java:81)
```

Comment: Do you have any particular question regarding the error?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes. What is file=uri? and whoami error

Comment: Hadoop tries to run `whoami` to figure out which user it's running as, and it does not seem to be able to find that command on your system. The URL part I have no idea about, but my guess is that you didn't set a path somewhere. Maybe not very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your IDE on Windows?

Try installing [unxutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) (unzip it somewhere), and putting the usr/local/wbin folder on your windows $PATH, restart your IDE (or add the path to your IDE runtime path) and try again